# Jquery clear div

Tags: jquery

I am trying to clear an html box that is populated by the function updatemykad, when asd3 gets a value, it loads a json script and the div, isresultexperience is loaded with data. However, I would like to clear this div, before new data is loaded. For some reason the code below doesn't work. Any ideas?

```js
function updatemykad(mykad) {
     $('#isresultsexperience').html('55585285');
  $('#asd3').val(mykad).trigger("input");   
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="searchmykad" href="#" onclick="updatemykad(34234234);return false;">James Dean</a>

      <div id="isresultsexperience">   </div>

       <input type="text" id="asd3" name="asd3" value="" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Search Name..." class="input-block-level" placeholder="Search Mykad..." maxlength="12" style="width:100%; display:none;"  />
```

Comment: Can you provide the rest of your html please?

Comment: $('#asd3') is not in your html example btw maybay add some more code

Comment: @Rickert I added it, it updates perfectly fine and works, its just the clearing that is an issue. Its a hidden input box.

Comment: it seems to work fine when I run the snippet in your question.

Comment: So you are saying that the value `55585285` is not appearing before the Ajax all is fired? I am guessing the Ajax call is triggered via the oninput event?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on jsfiddle when I put it in the js section, but when I put it on the `<script>` tag on top in the html section it worked

This could fix the problem:

```
$(document).on('click','#searchmykad',function(){
    updatemykad(1234);
});
```

I've read that it's better to add a event to a element than use the onclick attribute but I don't know if that is true.